# get connection relations from laravel Connection

Tags: database, laravel, connection

How can I get all database attributes by using Laravel?
I've used `DB::connection('new_mysql_connection')->getPdo()`
Now I need to get available relations for this connection.
I can get tables by

```
$tables = DB::connection('new_mysql_connection')
                ->select('SHOW TABLES');
```

But how can I get other attributes like relations or views from this database?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just used mysql queries to get all database, tables and columns attributes:
for getting all tables name list:

```
$tables = $connection->select('SHOW FULL TABLES');
$t = 'Tables_in_' . $connection->getDatabaseName();
```

for getting all columns relations

```
$relations = DB::select('
                 SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, 
                 REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
                 FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?
                 AND TABLE_NAME = ?
                 AND COLUMN_NAME = ?
                 AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL', [$database, $table_name, $column_name]);
```

For getting columns detail such as nullability!, default, data_type etc:

```
$column_details = DB::select('SHOW COLUMNS FROM `'. $table .'` FROM `'. $database .'` WHERE Field = "'. $column .'"');
```

And to see if the column is index or not:

```
$index = DB::select('
             SELECT *
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? 
             AND TABLE_NAME = ? 
             AND COLUMN_NAME = ?;', [$database, $table, $column]);
```